# Program that would ask for min, hours , AM and PM

Tags: c++

I would like to create a Program that would ask for min, hours , AM and PM but what I want it  to do is add one to the current entered mint when it it displaying the curent time. For example : I will enter the hour: 5, enter the minute: 23 enter AM or PM: AM and gives me the new time as 5:24 AM, I also would like it to change the time and AM or PM if entered some thing lik this, enter the hour: 11 enter the minute: 59 enter AM or PM: AM
The new time is 12 00 PM . Also changing the time If I got to 12:59AM to 1:00AM.
This is what I have done so far but have no Idea how to make time loop around. I also would like to make this with out any classes. This thing is frustrating me and going no where .

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int hr = hr;
        int min = min;
            int period = period;
            currentTime

            int time;
                    time = hr * 60 + min + 1;
                    hr = time / 60;
                    min = time % 60;
                    currentTime = currentTime(5, 59, "AM");
                    cout<<currentTime .hr +" : "+currentTime .min +" "+currentTime .period;
                             cin>>hrs;

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't complete enough to make a real question. You'll have to actually try to write it, and then if you have specific problems, you can ask here. If you really don't know where to start, I'd recommend going through a good tutorial, and writing simpler programs for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code, would produce a similar output to what you're looking for, but without the loop you wanted to create, because I'm sure that would require a fair few `if` statements.

I was curious as what this line was doing `currentTime` because it doesn't look to me like it would do anything at all.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int hr, min;
    char period;

    cout << "Enter Hour" << endl;
    cin >> hr;

    cout << "Enter Minute" << endl;
    cin >> min;
    min++;

    cout << "Enter Period (A or P)" << endl;
    cin >> period;

    cout << "Current Time: " <<  hr << ":" << min << " " << period << "M" << endl;

    _getch();

}
```

Comment: this is just a simple loop . does not do anything. When I put in for example 11:59 am the out put is 11:60 am , which has to be 12:00 pm how could I get it to work with time?

Comment: Adding in two `if` statements will fix that.

if(min == 60){ ... }
if(hr == 13) { ... }

Answer (score -1):

Here is an idea of how to accomplish this in C#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double hrs=0;
            double mins=0;
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013, 10, 20, 3, 59, 00);

            //dt = DateTime.Now;

            Console.WriteLine(dt.ToShortTimeString());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter hours:");
            hrs = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            dt = dt.AddHours(hrs);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter minutes:");
            mins = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            dt = dt.AddMinutes(mins);

            if (dt.Minute == 59)
                dt = dt.AddMinutes(1);

            Console.WriteLine(dt.ToShortTimeString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```